# Is it possible to use OpenNLP for HTML formatted text content?

Tags: parsing, html-parsing, text-mining, apache-tika, opennlp

I need to insert CSS id's into an HTML document to mark paragraphs and sentences.
There are so many different ways of formatting HTML that it is extremely hard to find a consistent method to parse them. For example, some crappy html use `<table>`, others use `<P>`, some others use `<div>`, etc. Some use combinations.

INPUT:

```
<p> This is a sentence, with stuff.  Mr. John doe was walking down the street. Mrs. Daisy knows how to drive but does not drive.  The car is fast, but is an ugly color.  This is an example of a paragraph. </P>

<br>

<div> However, sometimes, paragraphs on HTML pages are not tagged as with a consistent format.  This makes it hard to identify paragraphs and sentences.  I need a solution to tag them with CSS id's</div>
```

OUTPUT

```
 <p><span id="paragraph1"> <span id="sentence1">This is a sentence, with stuff.</span><span id="sentence2">  Mr. John doe was walking down the street. </span><span id="sent3"> Mrs. Daisy knows how to drive but does not drive. </span> <span id="sent4"> The car is fast, but is an ugly color.</span>  <span id="sent4"> This is an example of a paragraph.</span> </span> </P>

</br>

<div><span id="paragraph2"> <span id="sent5">However, sometimes, paragraphs on HTML pages are not tagged as with a consistent format.</span><span id="sent6">  This makes it hard to identify paragraphs and sentences.</span> <span id="sent7"> I need a solution to tag them with CSS id's</span></span></div>
```

1) What solution can be used to identify paragraphs in HTML and tag them.

2) OpenNLP is great for identifying sentences, but I didn't see a html stripper.

I was thinking I could use Tika to strip the HTML and feed it into OpenNLP to identify sentences, but than I lose all formatting and would not know where to put the tags back into the original HTML.

Comment: You don't want to *strip* the HTML, you want to modify the contents *within* HTML and put it back.

Comment: Why would you delete the YAML/hash question??? I spent time answering it, it's a valid question, and you took it away from everybody.

Comment: 1) Yes, you are correct, I want to modify the HTML and put it back.    2) my apologizes for deleting the YAML/HTML question. I did not realize it was answered before I deleted it.  I would say that YAML.load rather than Psch.parse was a good solution, which I picked up in an IRC. you answered it very quickly from the time I posted it and I thank you!  Next time I will be more careful.

Comment: Additionally though, openNLP needs stripped code to process correctly.  Therefore, although my goal is to modify and put it back, it needs to be stripped for openNLP to process it.  It's complicated and I'm not very sure how to proceed with it.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you need to parse the HTML, gathering the inner text of the DOM elements in question. Process it, and replace it (put it back into the original document).

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to code some thing following your recommendation.